# How to use I18n from controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a PetsController in which a flash message is setted. Something like this:

```
class PetsController

  ...

  def treat_dog
    #do somthing
    flash[:success] = 'Your dog is being treated.'
  end

  ...

end
```

this controller belongs to Admin, so it is located at: `app/controllers/admin/pets_controller.rb`. I will use I18n, so I replaced the string in controller with `t('controllers.admin.pet.treated')`, then,I wrote this yml:

```
en:
  controllers:
    admin:
      pet:
        treated: "Your dog is being treated."
```

located at: `config/locales/controllers/admin/pet/en.yml` and it did not work. I have attempted locating it at `config/locales/controllers/admin/pets/en.yml`, `config/locales/controllers/admin/en.yml`
`config/locales/controllers/en.yml`
and none of these worked, the translation is not found.

How can I use a translation from this controller?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In controller you use it like this

```
I18n.t 'controllers.admin.pet.treated'
```

Using `t()` directly enables lazy loading:

```
t(".treated") #loads from key: controllers.admin.pet.treated
```

Comment: Yes, I have found that by convention, in controllers I18n translation must be used with I18n.t 'key' instead of t('key') but this last must work too. In my case, exchange it works for me. Thanks Mahesh.

Comment: As explained in the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#lazy-lookup you could probably simplify that with lazy lookups using the helper like this `t('.treated')`

Comment: Bear in mind that both I18n.t 'key' and t('key') will work in controllers, but only the t('key') helper supports lazy loading via the t('.key') shortcut.

Comment: ```Using t() directly enables lazy loading:```


Lazing loading (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) is a completely different concept from what is happening in your second example.  Rails calls it "lazy lookup".

Answer (score 0):

```
def treat_dog
    #do somthing
    flash[:success] = t('controllers.admin.pet.treated')
end
```

Comment: I forgot write the simple quotation marks in the question,but I really used it

Answer (score 0):

Put it into `config/locales/en.yml` and it should work (you may need to restart the server).

This guide should help clear the head about I18n. I'm giving link to relevant section, but read it in full: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-translations

If you insist on using nested files, you need to enable it. Documentation says:

> The default locale loading mechanism in Rails does not load locale files in nested dictionaries, like we have here. So, for this to work, we must explicitly tell Rails to look further:

```
# config/application.rb
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

Comment: the yml's located at `config/locales/en.yml` are used to set the general or generic tranlations.When you have a lot of tranlations, you can locate them with the same hierarchy order than `view` and `controller` tree.

Comment: @IvánCortésRomero: hah, didn't know about it! However, do read that guide. It mentions that nested files are not loaded by default and how to enable it.

Comment: I did'n know about that configuration,so I have checked my `config/application.rb` and I found already this line. However, thank youa lot.

Answer (score 0):

In callback it should be:

```
add_breadcrumb proc{ I18n.t('home_page') }, :root_path
```